# assembly language?

Tags: assembly

Does asm language get a steep learning curve for someone who dont have a CS background (my major is applied maths)?

Usually how long it takes somebody who is familiar with some higher-level programming language like C/C++ etc. to write asm programs that can at least do some elemental math computation like linear regression, 1D orthogonal polynomial computation and such?

Btw, does modern asm support some features like:

- Math ops with SIMD instructions
- multi-threading and thread-control

And usually is there much performance-gain by doing this in asm instead of C/C++ with some latest optimized compiler?

Comment: I've seen some benchmark that compiler-generated code is actually _faster_ than hand-created code, because that's what the CPU is optimised for.

Comment: Does it get a steep learning curve? How long does it take to write those programs? Depends on you. ANYTHING you can do with a HHL you can do with ASM, and with good brains(D'oh?), so those features will be there. With good brains, you can make the code as fast as the processor can run it(which can be up to a magnitude faster than C). Trust me, learning ASM will be worth it. So rest assured.

Comment: Please define "steep learning curve". If you call `c` a high-level programming language, you won't mind assembler. Printing manually is not nice, but there's a library for that.

Comment: The "steep learning curve" means if it takes months for me to do that job I may simply give up, but yes, as namehere talks, I will still try to learn something about asm, at least it will helping me swallow more information about my programs when debugging.

Comment: I am shaking my head here at the folks that think the compiler will beat hand-optimised assembler... People have been saying that with every new generation of CPU for at least as long as I've been programming, and I'm still waiting on that magical compiler. The CPU is optimised for *bad* code, because that's what compilers generate. Doesn't mean you can't write good code. Is it hard? Yes, absolutely. Would I write an entire program in it? No. But is it useful? Yes. There isn't a performance critical code-base I've worked on where it hasn't needed asm level optimisation.

Comment: @JasonD Does the Intel compiler too, produce "bad code"? And would you like to turn your comment into answer? For example, how much dedication/experience/work does it take to do asm level optimisation?

Comment: How can someone know if the compiler is producing good or bad code, if they can't understand the asm being generated? Even if all you do is optimise in C/C++, you'll be a lot more effective if you can understand what the compiler is doing, and what you want it to do. (And the Intel compiler *deliberately* generates code which is sub-optimal on non-Intel CPUs... not to mention not being terribly useful if you're not on an Intel platform at all). Anyway the answers here are fine, I just wanted to somewhat counter the disparaging tone of some comments.

Answer (score 4):

ASM is usually considered rather hard for most people. However, it is logically straightforward and simple, and I dont think someone with a background of applied maths will have a problem.

In assembly you need to understand how the processor works, because when coding asm you are ultimately manipulating the processor in the most fundemental way.

Consider this:

```
if (val)goto next;
```

Translates to something as long as this:

```
mov eax, [val]
cmp eax, 0
je next
```

In essence, Assembly requires an understanding of how a program uses the processor to do tasks. EG: How registers (like eax) are needed and used.

It takes longer to do things in asm over C in general. As for specifics, I do not know.

Some modern instruction sets provide new math operations which may or may not be what your after.
Multithreading and such is the role of the operating system and has NOTHING to do with the processor, hence nothing do to assembly (this is not strictly true, as hardware multitasking exists, but is rarely used, but I digress.)

There is usually very little performance gain writing ASM over optimized C/C++, unless your writing a small, repetitive piece of code which you spend alot of time optimizing.

Comment: Thanks, I just hope to improve my program a bit by replacing some critical part of codes with asm codes there, because in terms of gflops my programs achieved, it seems there is still quite some room for improvement when you compare it to the CPU's rated gflops (well I know there are alot of other factors like memory, cache, branching etc.).

Answer (score 1):

> And usually is there much performance-gain by doing this in asm instead of C/C++ with some latest optimized compiler?

No.

It's more difficult and more time-consuming to write asm: because each asm instruction is simpler than a HLL statement, you need more asm instructions to implement the same functionality. Writing in assembly has additional complications, e.g. that there's only a small number of registers.

Additionally, there are many ways to write assembly to achieve the same thing: for example, `mov eax,0` and `xor eax,eax` with both write zero into the `eax` register, but one is faster than the other. Furthermore, the sequence of asm instructions makes a difference to how fast it runs: a non-obvious or a longer sequence of instructions may be faster if it matches to keep [several CPU pipelines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_pipeline) busy.

Writing optimal assembly is compute-intensive: working out how long various possibilities might take, based on cycle-counting, accounting for pipelining, etc. Such computation is done by an optimizing compiler, which can probably do it better (faster and more accurately) than you can.

[http://www.amazon.com/Zen-Code-Optimization-Ultimate-Software/dp/1883577039](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1883577039) is a very interesting read, but by the end of the book, where it's starting to talk about Pentium-class CPUs, you can see that writing optimal assembly is getting complicated.

---

If you're not happy with your compiler's output, you might consider getting a better compiler: for example Intel's compiler produces (or at least used to produce) more-optimized than many other compilers, and included better support for specific CPUs, unusual opcodes, maybe had better run-time libraries, etc.